# Why JavaScript eval function throw exception for number property?

Tags: javascript

I have one object as below formate.

```
var pqr = {'1' : 'a1','b': 'b1'}
eval('pqr.1') //throw exception
eval('pqr.b') //This is working fine.
```

Please let me know why eval function throw an exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406)

Comment: Use `eval('pqr[1]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need eval here , if you still want to use it , use square braces , and to access `b` put it in a quotes otherwise `b` will be considered as variable

```js
var pqr = {
  '1': 'a1',
  'b': 'b1'
}
console.log(eval('pqr[1]')) //throw exception
console.log(eval('pqr["b"]'))
```